# Form expiring/timing out when Idle

Tags: safecracker

EE 2.9 - this is an issue with Channel Form: we have a large form to submit (50 fields or so) and it takes people quite a while to fill in the fields as some need a bit of thought.

The problem is that while this is happening and they are effectively idle, the form is timing out and when the user returns to it all the fields are blank which is a source of annoyance for them.

Is there any way of extending this period before the 'idle' timeout kicks in?

Comment: We a have a similar issue, could I ask if this was resolved?

Comment: wouldn't this be a php.ini setting?

Comment: 1. Split it into multiple pages, so they submit smaller sub bits at a time?
2. Javascript autosave (auto submit for, and then allow editing of it)

If the form is actually clearing itself without page submission or refresh? Then there must be some JS going on, but if you mean after submission when they finally get to the end, i image the form CSRF token is timing out.